# By using the Big Picard theorem show that $a$ is unique

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a non polynomial analytic function in the whole complex plane. Asume that the equation $f(s)=a$ has a finite number of solutions with respect to $s$. Here $a≠0$. My question is: By using the Big Picard theorem show that $a$ is unique.

Comment: It is irrelevant that $a\neq 0$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Yes. But we can consider $f(s)-a$ have finite number of solutions.

Comment: Try applying the big Picard theorem to the function $g(z)=f(1/z)$ with singularity at $z=0$. (Right. I wonder why it is stated in your problem that $a\neq 0$.)

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Since I am interested mainly on that value of $a$ to be unique.

Comment: ZE1: I do not understand your comment.  Uniquess of $a$ has nothing to do with the condition $a\neq 0$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Ah, Ok, I have a problem related to this question requiring that $a$ is unique. For example if $f$ is a polynomial, then $a$ cover all the complex plane.

Comment: ZE1: *This* problem states that $a$ is unique.  But that has nothing to do with the condition $a\neq 0$.  You essentially stated the reason for this in your first comment.  Yes, uniqueness is dependent on $f$ not being a polynomial.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will flesh out the hint given by Jonas Meyer in the comments. Note that the assumption $a\neq 0$ is not needed.

We first recall the Big Picard theorem.

> **Big Picard Theorem**: If an analytic function $f$ has an essential singularity at a point $w$, then on any punctured neighborhood of $w$,
>   $f(z)$ takes on all possible complex values, with at most a single
>   exception, infinitely often.

By assumption, our given $f(z)$ has an infinite power series when expanded at $0$. This means that $f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$. By the theorem (taking the neighborhood to be $\mathbb C\backslash \{0\}$), there is at most one value $w$ such that $f(1/z)$ takes on $w$ a finitely number of times. Hence there is at most a single $a$ such that $f(z)$ takes on $a$ a finite number of times. (The value at $0$ doesn't matter, because it won't make the difference between some value being taking a finite or being taken an infinite number of times.)

Comment: 'at most' implies unicity of $a$.

Comment: @ZE1 There could be no such $a$. (Or am I misunderstanding your remark?)

Comment: I want to see if $a$ is unique by your above analysis: *Hence there is at most a single a such that $f(z)$ takes on $a$ a finite number of times*

Comment: @Ze1 Yes. If there were two such values, then there would be two values that $f(1/z)$ takes only a finite number of times (do you see why?), contradicting Picard's Big Theorem.

Comment: @ZE1 If the function were constant, it would not satisfy the hypotheses of the problem, because it would be a polynomial.